# How to append to a LinkedList inside a HashMap?

Tags: list, scala, dictionary

Given is the following construct

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap 
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList
private var log = new HashMap[String, LinkedList[String]]
```

How do I append to the linked list?

If I use `log.get("some key").get :+ some_string` or `log.get("some key").get append LinkedList(some_string)` the list is not appended but a new list containing the value is returned. Does HashMap only return a copy of the associated value instead of a reference to the value?

*Off topic: Can someone with a high reputation add scala as a title-enabled tag? It should as it is a fairly known programming language.*

Comment: Your version using `append` works - check it again. (But it's better not to use `get` on the `Option` - use `map` instead.)

Comment: I have, checked it a lot. Maybe there's a version difference? I am using Scala 2.10.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself after trying around a lot: it worked using a `ListBuffer` instead of a `LinkedList`.

Comment: `LinkedList` isn't really a commonly used collection anyway. Better to go totally immutable and use collections like `immutable.Map` and `Vector`. You then update the reference of `log`. These immutable collections are actually very efficient because they can re-use the existing structure.

Answer (score 0):

Using your second solution it works for me:

```
>scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_06).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

scala> import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList

scala> var log = new HashMap[String, LinkedList[String]]
log: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[String]] = Map()

scala> log += ("abc" -> LinkedList("apple", "banana", "coconut"))
res0: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[String]] = Map(abc
 -> LinkedList(apple, banana, coconut))

scala> log.get("abc").get append LinkedList("durian")
res1: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[String] = LinkedList(apple, banana, coconut, durian)

scala> log("abc")
res2: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[String] = LinkedList(apple, banana, coconut, durian)
```

although, better than `get` is

```
log.get("abc") foreach (_ append LinkedList("elderberry"))
```

which won't throw an exception if it can't find the value.